# BigQuery, How to Group by Week End not start

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to write a Query That return a week calendar, but the week end has to be dynamic based on a date parameter, here is the code

```
SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE) as cutoff,
CASE
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%A',PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)) ="Monday" THEN DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Monday))
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%A',PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)) ="Tuesday" THEN DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Tuesday))
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%A',PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)) ="Wednesday" THEN DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Wednesday))
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%A',PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)) ="Thursday" THEN DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Thursday))
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%A',PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)) ="Friday" THEN DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Friday))
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%A',PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)) ="Saturday" THEN DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Saturday))
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%A',PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)) ="Sunday" THEN DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Sunday))
  ELSE
  NULL
END
  AS week
FROM `xxxxxx-bi-engine.Reporting.datastudio` WHERE date <= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
```

the result returned is by week start

[image]

what I want is to be grouped by Week End like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `INTERVAL 1 WEEK` to the start of week to get its end. Note, that I also replaced expensive `FORMAT_DATE(%A)` with `EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM)`

```
SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', DS_END_DATE) as cutoff,
CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', DS_END_DATE)) = 2 THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Monday)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', DS_END_DATE)) = 3 THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Tuesday)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', DS_END_DATE)) = 4 THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Wednesday)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', DS_END_DATE)) = 5 THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Thursday)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', DS_END_DATE)) = 6 THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Friday)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', DS_END_DATE)) = 7 THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Saturday)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', DS_END_DATE)) = 1 THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(Sunday)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
  ELSE
  NULL
END
  AS week
```